# socket.io is not found when listening to different port than server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have set up a server in node.js using socket.io and epxress.

When I set it up as shown below, it works like charm (now it's listening on 8080).

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var io = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, host);
var scoketIO = io.listen(server);
```

But I need it to listen to different port, and if I try eg. 8000

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, host);
var scoketIO = io.listen(8000);
```

I get the following error:
`GET http://10.0.33.34:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found).` Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Does this error occur on client or server side?

Comment: What is the value of `port` variable in `http.createServer(app).listen(port, host); ?` I think it should be `8000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var io = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
var port = 8000;
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port, host);
var scoketIO = io.listen(server);
```

Above code is not tested but most likely it will not fail. Pass port value to listen method of http.createServer(app).

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express')
http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8000);

//Code needs to be in this order
```

and check in the script that the port is 8000

```
<script src=""></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the script in you html ?

Maybe change the include to the port 8000.

```
<script src="http://10.0.33.34:8000/socket.io/"></script>
```